# Performance tuning of Delete statement in ORACLE

Tags: oracle11g

Performance tuning of Delete statement in ORACLE.we have sql statement inside stored procedure

```
delete my_table where trunc(sysdate)-trunc(col_id) >:B1;
```

we need to delete 4 million data using above query.it is taking around 20 min to execute.how to tune this queryto get faster result.

Comment: Welcome to SO: You might get better responses by moving this question to [http://dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four million rows doesn't sound like using an index would help. Maybe parallelization does. Try a hint:

```
delete /*+parallel(my_table,8)*/ my_table where trunc(sysdate)-trunc(col_id) >:B1;
```

Comment: Thanks.It really helped.